# How to make a CSS div set auto height to content

Tags: css

I this strange CSS problem. I have two boxes like in the code bellow:

```
#mainbox{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    left:0px;
    min-height: 700px;
    background-color:#0052b0;
    display: inline-block;
}

#contentbox{
    width:80%;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    background-color:white;
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#0052b0;
    min-height:700px;
    top:-50px;
}
```

#contentbox is inside #mainbox. The problem is that when content height exceeds the inner box limit, the inner box will increase it's height, to wrap the content. But this doesn't happen to #mainbox, which is the outer box.

Can anyone help me get this fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `position:absolute;`
and replace it with `position:relative;`

```
#contentbox{
width:80%;
left:10%;
position:relative;
background-color:white;
border-width:5px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#0052b0;
min-height:700px;
top:-50px;
}
```